# Склонения в русском языке

Tags: склонение, недопустимая-метка

Какого склонения слово "время"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Время — это разносклоняемое существительное, так же как остальные слова на -мя: темя, племя, пламя, вымя, бремя, знамя, стремя и слово путь.

Answer (score 1):

В древнерусском языке оно относится к 4 склонению, которое в современном исчезло